# statistic syntax in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to do some statistic for the `Point` in my appliation,this is the columns for `Point` table:

```
id   type   city
1    food   NewYork
2    food   Washington
3    sport  NewYork
4    food   .....
```

Each point belongs to a certain type and located at the certain city.

Now I want to caculate the numbers of points  in different city for each type.

For example, there are two types here :`food` and `sport`.

Then I want to know:

```
how many points of `food` and `sport` at NewYork
how many points of `food` and `sport` at Washington
how many points of `food` and `sport` at Chicago
......
```

I have tried this:

```
select type,count(*) as num from point group by type ;
```

But I can not group the by the city.

How to make it?

### **Update**

```
id      type        city
1       food        NewYork
2       sport       NewYork
3       food        Chicago
4       food        San
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
        NewYork     Chicago     San
food    2           1           1
sport   1           0           0
```

I will use the html table and chart to display these datas.

So I need to do the counting, I can use something like this:

```
select count(*) from point where type='food' and city ='San'
select count(*) from point where type='food' and city ='NewYork'
....
```

However I think this is a bad idea,so I wonder if I can use the sql to do the counting.

BTW,for these table data,how do people organization their structure using json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

To get the results in an aggregated row/column format you need to use a pivot table. In Access it's called a [Crosstab query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx). You can use the Crosstab query wizard to generate the query via a nice UI or cut straight to the SQL:

```
TRANSFORM COUNT(id) AS CountOfId
   SELECT type
     FROM point
 GROUP BY type
    PIVOT city
```

The grouping is used to count the number of Id's for each `type`. The additional `PIVOT` clause groups the data by `city` and displays each grouping in a separate column. The end result looks something like this:

```
        NewYork     Chicago     San
food    2           1           1
sport   1           0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

this's what you want:

```
    SELECT city, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN [type] = 'food' THEN 1 END) AS FoodCount,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN [type] = 'sport' THEN 1 END) AS SportCount
    FROM point
    GROUP BY city
```